Unable to open camera for CSİ Camera
The CSI camera works in the terminal, but it doesn’t work with Python in Visual Studio. I’m using a Jetson Orin Nano. The camera works when I run the following command in the terminal:
gst-launch-1.0 nvarguscamerasrc ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=1280, height=720, framerate=30/1' ! nvvidconv ! nvegltransform ! nveglglessink -e
However, the camera does not work in the following Python script:
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("nvarguscamerasrc ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=1280, height=720, framerate=30/1 ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw, format=BGRx ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! appsink")

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        print("Unable to capture camera image")
        break

    cv2.imshow("CSI Camera", frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

I receive the following output when I run the script:
onur@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Project$ /bin/python /home/onur/Desktop/Project/simple_camera.py
nvarguscamerasrc sensor-id=0 ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, framerate=(fraction)30/1 ! nvvidconv flip-method=0 ! video/x-raw, width=(int)960, height=(int)540, format=(string)BGRx ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR ! appsink
Error: Unable to open camera

Upon researching, I was advised to run the following code:
import cv2
print(cv2.getBuildInformation())

In the output, I saw:
Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (59.37.100)
      avformat:                  YES (59.27.100)
      avutil:                   YES (57.28.100)
      swscale:                  YES (6.7.100)
      avresample:                NO
    GStreamer:                   NO
    v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)

It seems that the GStreamer: NO line indicates a problem. How can I solve this?

How did you install opencv for python? In my jetson I see that it was installed by libopencv-python and I see GStreamer enabled.
Also I see the resolution for both pipelines are different, make sure you try the same.

You have to build opencv with gstreamer enabled.
https://qengineering.eu/install-opencv-on-orin-nano.html
follow this one and read script there's lots of options to select(like cuda, cudnn something like this)
